# overlapping elements in HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML template in flask which is defined as follows. I am using semantic UI and using some fading message to notify users when something has been copied to clipboard as follows:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scan</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

    

    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='clipboard.js')}}"></script>
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='alerts.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    

<body>
   <br />
   <!--<h1 align="center">Please paste text in the box below</h1>-->

   <div class="ui container left aligned">
        <div class="ui top attached segment">
            <div class="ui top attached massive green label">HPO Extraction Results</div>
            <br /><br />
            <form class="ui form">
            <table class="ui table" id="hpos">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Text</th>
                        <th>Count</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="collapsing">
                            <div class="ui checked checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked=""> <label></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            
        </form>
        <br />
        <button class="ui left floated positive submit button" id="csv-button">Copy to Clipboard</button>
            <script>
                $("#csv-button").click(getCSV);
            </script>
            
            <div style="height:10px; width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="alert-box success" float:left>Copied to clipboard</div>
            <div class="alert-box failure" float:left>Could not copy results</div>
            <div style="height:20px; width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS for this alert is defined as:

```
.alert-box {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;  
}

.success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    display: none;
}
```

The javascript function is simply:

```
function getCSV() {
    
    $( "div.success" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
}
```

Now, my issue is no matter what I do, the alert gets overlapped with the button. I am trying to find a solution that would allow me to simply manage this without too much fuss as this is just a PoC. See, the screenshot below to see what happens:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be caused by a style that you have not shared. It works with the code here.

**Updated:** It works if you remove the `left floated` classes from the original button.

```js
$("#csv-button").click(getCSV);

function getCSV() {
    
    $( "div.success" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
}
```

```css
.alert-box {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;  
}

.success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scan</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

    

    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='clipboard.js')}}"></script>
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='alerts.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    

<body>
   <br />
   <!--<h1 align="center">Please paste text in the box below</h1>-->

   <div class="ui container left aligned">
        <div class="ui top attached segment">
            <div class="ui top attached massive green label">HPO Extraction Results</div>
            <br /><br />
            <form class="ui form">
            <table class="ui table" id="hpos">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Text</th>
                        <th>Count</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="collapsing">
                            <div class="ui checked checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked=""> <label></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            
        </form>
        <br />
        <button class="ui positive submit button" id="csv-button">Copy to Clipboard</button>
            
            <div style="height:10px; width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="alert-box success" float:left>Copied to clipboard</div>
            <div class="alert-box failure" float:left>Could not copy results</div>
            <div style="height:20px; width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question to add the full template code. I guess it is something to do with the semantic UI and I will investigate further

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you! Weird though...